# Char to date in SAS proq sql

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I have column of sql table with next observations:

```
AB_191007_01
AB_190930_02
```

I want to convert this column to date in another column with format yyyy-mm-dd.

```
proc sql;
CREATE TABLE result AS
SELECT input(compress(col_name,"AB_"), ANYDTDTE6.) AS col_date  format=yymmdd6.
FROM work.test
;quit;
```

The previous code ruturns me some strange results:

```
2009-06-18
1926-12-17
1926-12-17
2009-06-18
2006-08-18
2016-05-18
2011-03-19
1926-12-17
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you would like to convert the character AB_191007_01 to the date 2019-10-07, use the SCAN function to get the middle date piece between the underscores, then INPUT as yymmdd6. You can then change the format if desired (I used yymmdd10.).

```
SELECT input(scan(col_name,2,"_"),yymmdd6.) AS col_date format yymmdd10.
```

Comment: Ty, i got it via ''' SELECT input(substr(col_name,4,6),yymmdd6.) AS col_date format yymmdd10.
'''

Answer (score 0):

1. `ANYDTDTE` informat depends on your `DATESTYLE` option (which is in turn dependent on `LOCALE`), so you should either specify it or use another, fixed position informat, e.g. `yymmdd6`.
2. Reading year 26 as 1926 or 2026 depends on your `YEARCUTOFF` option.
3. `compress()` function as written also compresses second _, so you supply to `input()` more characters than intended (though it should not affect .6 informat).